# why am i getting this Error:connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 while writing mocha js test

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js

I have taken a sample random nodejs code named f.js and writing unit test for that.
the node js code is below,

```js
//storing the information in temporary memory
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var parsedUrl = url.parse('/itemsAvailable?model=nokia', true)
// href: '/itemsAvailable?model=nokia',
//search: '?model=nokia',
//query: {model: 'nokia'},
//pathname: '/itemsAvailable'


//information of the user 
function reset() {
  var d = new Date();
  var date = d.getDate();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var min = d.getMinutes();
  //var time = hour + ':'+min;
  //console.log(date,itemsAvailable[2].count,itemsAvailable[2].userId);

  if (hour == 16 && min == 52) {
    itemsAvailable[2].count = 0;
  }
}
exports.reset = reset;

var itemsAvailable = [{
    model: 'nokia',

    available: 10
  },
  {
    model: 'samsung',
    available: 20
  },
  {
    userId: 1234,
    count: 0, //initially assigning count to 0 
    model: "",

  }
]; //create an object to store the itemsAvailable
exports.itemsAvailable = itemsAvailable;

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  reset(); //calling the reset after every request
  res.write("hello\n");
  if (itemsAvailable[2].count == 0) {
    if (parsedUrl.query.model === 'nokia' && itemsAvailable[0].available != 0) { //parsedUrl.query gives an object and .model gives nokia
      res.write("item chosen is nokia\n")
      res.write("item can be bought");
      itemsAvailable[2].count++; // increasing the num of mobiles bought 
      console.log(itemsAvailable[2].count);
      itemsAvailable[0].available--;
      console.log(itemsAvailable[0].available)

    }
  } else {
    res.write("u cannot buy the item today come back tomorrow");
  }

  res.end()
}).listen(3000);

exports.server = server;
```

The test code i have written is below

```js
var assert = require("chai").assert;

var http = require("http");

var Code = require("../f");


describe("itemsAvailable", function() {
  it("information count", function() {
    assert.equal(Code.itemsAvailable[2].count, 0);
  })

});


describe("information count", function() {
  it("reset", function() {
    if (Code.reset.hour == 16 && Code.reset.min == 52) {
      assert.equal(Code.reset.itemsAvailable[2].count, 0);
    }
  });
})



describe('/', function() {

  before(function(done) {
    Code.server.listen(3000, done);
  });

  after(function(done) {
    Code.server.close();
  });

  describe("http request", function() {

    it('buy the item', function(done) {

      http.get("http://localhost:3000", function(res) {

        //assert.equal(Code.server.res,'hello');
        try {
          if (Code.itemsAvailable[2].count == 0) {
            if (Code.parsedUrl.query.model == 'nokia' && Code.itemsAvailable[0].available != 0) {

              it("item can be bought", function(done) {
                assert.equal(Code.server.res, 'item chosen is nokia');
                assert.equal(Code.server.res, 'item can be bought');
                done();
              })
            }
          };
        } catch (error) {
          it("item can not be bought", function(done) {
            assert.equal(Code.server.res, 'u cannot buy the item today come back tomorrow');
            done();
          })
        }
      })
      done();
    })

  });
})
```

Iam getting the error

> 3 passing and 1 failing 
>   1) after all hook uncaught error : error econnrefused 127.0.0.1:3000

iam listening to the port 3000 .The nodejs code alone works fine . I just started learning mocha unit testing , can someone explain me why that error occurs and what changes can be done in the above unit test code to possibly get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code:

1. You cannot nest `it` calls. Mocha simply does not support such nesting and will behave erratically if you try it.
2. In the test `buy the item` you call `done` *outside* your callback to `http.get`. This is wrong. It causes your test to end prematurely.

   *This* is the direct cause of the error you got. The problem is that `http.get` only guarantees a result *at some undetermined point in the future*. By finishing your test prematurely, Mocha moves on to your `after` hook. (The two `it` tests that are nested in your `buy the item` test do not matter: Mocha does not even *know* about these nested tests at this point.) So Mocha considers that your test is done, and executes the `after` hook, which closes the server, and *after that*, it tries to run the request for `http.get` which fails because the server is closed. The error is reported as an error in the `after` hook because that's where Mocha is in its sequence of execution when `http.get` fails.
3. You fail to call `done` in your `after` hook.

Your `describe('/'` block should be structured like this instead of what you currently have:

```
describe('/', function() {

  before(function(done) {
    Code.server.listen(3000, done);
  });

  after(function(done) {
    // Make sure to call the done callback after the server is closed.
    Code.server.close(done);
  });

  describe("http request", function() {
    it('buy the item', function(done) {

      http.get("http://localhost:3000", function(res) {
        // Perform your tests here.

        // You must have your done call **inside** the callback to
        // http.get.
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

You can add as many `it` calls with `http.get` requests in them to cover all the cases you want to cover.

Comment: Thankyou all the tests are passing now :) I nested 'it' calls , it still works . Is it not recommended to use nesting for 'it' call ?

Comment: Yeah, don't use nested `it` calls. Mocha does not support such nesting.